# ResteasyClient not releasing connections

Tags: java, resteasy

I am currently running into an issue where my RestEasyClient is not releasing connections after closing the response object.    In my local environment it works, but when I deploy to a CentOS Tomcat 7 instance, the connections do not get released until some time later.

Here is a sample of how I initialize the client :

```
ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().connectionPoolSize(20)
    .connectionTTL(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .establishConnectionTimeout(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .maxPooledPerRoute(20)
    .build();
```

Here is a sample of how use the client / consume the response :

```
final ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(url);
Response response = null;
try {
    response = target.request().post(Entity.json(postBody));
    final String jsonMsg = response.readEntity(String.class);
    return mapper.readValue(jsonMsg, new TypeReference<List<String>>() {});
} catch (final Exception e) {
    log.error("error", e);
} finally {
    if (null != response) {
        response.close();
    }
}
```

Here was the stack trace :

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Unable to invoke request
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:287)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:407)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocationBuilder.post(ClientInvocationBuilder.java:195)
```

Caused by :

```
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for connection
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager.leaseConnection(PoolingClientConnectionManager.java:232)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager$1.getConnection(PoolingClientConnectionManager.java:199)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:455)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:283)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated - I have been scratching my head for days on this one.

Comment: Do you have a "caused by" section in the stacktrace ?

Comment: Yes, I modified the original post.

Comment: I figured out the issue.  There was one instance where I was not closing the response.  Doh!  Thanks for the quick response, alfasin.